# ¿Como automatizar la activación de windows ink para tabletas graficas con AutoHotKeys? (respondida)

Tags: windows, autohotkey

Hace poco me compré una tableta grafica Huion HS64, la uso por facilidad en el estudio, la docencia y el desarrollo, esto hizo que poco a poco fuera cambiando el mouse por esta. En este proceso me encontré que usar WindowsInk podía hacer que algunas funciones en varios programas fueran bastante molestas de usar, lo que me llevaba a tener que abrir constantemente el panel de configuración de la tablet para activar y desactivar esta opción. Para esto desarrollé un código en AutoHotKeys que funciona a la perfección en mi Huion HS64. El script .ahk es el siguiente:

```
^!h:: ; Ctrl+Alt+H
BlockInput On
run, "E:\Huion Tablet\Huion Tablet.exe"
if WinExist("Huion Tablet")
WinActivate ;
sleep, 150 ;
Click, 50, 156 ;
Click, 160, 570 ;
Click, 650, 630 ;
BlockInput Off
return
```

Si bien este funciona en la interfaz de Huion, creo que la logica es aplicable en otras marcas. Espero les sirva

¿Tienen algún otro código que también sea funcional?

Answer (score -1):

Aquí esta la versión del código para la tableta xppen g640s

Publicado originalmente en: https://www.xp-pen.com/forum-64.html

```
#z::Run https://www.autohotkey.com ; Win+Z
^!n:: ; Ctrl+Alt+N
BlockInput On
run, "C:\Program Files\Pentablet\PenTablet.exe"
if WinExist("PenTablet")
WinActivate ;
Click, 15, 597 ;
Click, 400, 600 ;
run, "C:\Program Files\Pentablet\PenTablet.exe"
if WinExist("PenTablet")
WinActivate ;
Click, 15, 597 ;
Click, 400, 600 ;
BlockInput Off
return
```